# Solve $x_{n+1}=2x_n-n^3$

Tags: systems-of-equations, z-transform

I want to solve this difference equation, using the z-transforms.

Using a table I get that:

$x_{n+1}\rightarrow zX(z)$

$2x_n\rightarrow 2X(z)$

but then I cannot find any entry for $-n^3$. Using WA this transform is meant to be

$-\frac{(z (1 + 4 z + z^2))}{(-1 + z)^4}$

But how is this found using a table? I thought of using the definition

$\sum_0^\infty -\frac{n^3}{z^k}$, but I am not sure how this turns  into the WA result.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The z-transform of $x_n = 1$ (constant) is equal to $X(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$. Then, use the  [rule of differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties) three times to find the z-transform of $x_n=n^3$.

Comment: You can easily write down the solution without using any transforms.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Kavi, I am not sure how that would come out, unless you show an example. Thanks

Comment: @AndreasLenz in my notes, the transform of 1 is $\frac{z}{z-1}$. Did you re-write it in another way?

Comment: @Luthier: This depends on the definition of the z-transform. Probably, in your notes the transform is defined as $X(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0}x_nz^{-n}$, while I was assuming a definition without the minus in the exponent.

Comment: Right, it was written as such. Since the rule is $nx_n\rightarrow -zX'(z)$,  how do you relate $x_n=1$ with three times differentiation and third degree exponent?

Comment: What do you get, if you multiply $1$ three times with $n$?

Comment: $n$....I am not sure I follow: Do you mean we can write: $(nx_n)^3=-z^3X^{(3)}(z)$?

Comment: I mean: Start with $x_n=1$. Then, apply rule of differentiation to $x_n$ and obtain $y_n=n$. Then, apply rule of differentiation to $y_n$, which gives you $z_n=n y_n = n^2$. Now, apply rule of differentation to $z_n$ and you end up with $w_n=n z_n = n^3$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think I know what you mean now. Thanks!